# vscode interractive windows jupyter won't pass muliple lines

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Everything has worked fine since this morning.
I have some issues with vscode when I pass the python code to the jupyter interactive windows.

If I select only one line of the code, the line is sent to the interactive windows using the default key bind <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> or the right-click menu.

However, when selecting multiple lines will not send to the interactive windows with any method and will not provide any feedback.

Attempt to solve the problem :

- change key binding
- remove similar key binding to ovoid conflict
- enable or disable python preference Data science allows input
- Uninstall and install vscode

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem happen after the update of the python extension.

Solution : install the previous version of the python extension in vscode

Comment: The switch to `conda run` in the latest release broke this functionality. It will be fixed in the next point release (aiming for Monday).